# How can I put a table here?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

For example 
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1& -1 & 1 & -1 \\ \hline
 & & &\\ \hline
 &  & &\\ \hline
 &  & &\\ \hline.
\end{tabular} 
Does not work here.

Comment: You should ask this at the [TeX Stack Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/)  site, rather than here.

Comment: @DavidMitra: It looks more like a MathJax question than a TeX one, so it should go to meta.MSE rather than tex.SE.

Comment: I know that this works in the latex. My problem is that in my answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251583/put-into-each-cell-one-number-1-or-one-number-1-that-the-sums-of-number-in-each/251638#251638 is difficult to see.

Comment: In my latex I can see. Here is that I can not see.

Comment: Search among questions with a TeX-tag. For example [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4240/11619) shows up. Zev's advice helped me.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4240/how-do-i-insert-a-table-when-asking-a-question
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/tabular-in-mathjax
and
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5044#5044

Comment: First you need to tell us your [axioms for **tables,** chairs *and* beer mugs.](http://www.google.com/search?q=axioms+tables+chairs+beer)

Answer (score 36):

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1& -1 & 1 & -1 \\ \hline
 & & &\\ \hline
 &  & &\\ \hline
 &  & &\\ \hline
\end{array}

---

```
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1& -1 & 1 & -1 \\ \hline
 & & &\\ \hline
 &  & &\\ \hline
 &  & &\\ \hline
\end{array}
```

Comment: Thank yo,, this help, but I would want like a chessboard.

Comment: There is a mistake with the last \hline having a full stop after it. Remove the full stop and you'll get a bottom line on the array.

Answer (score 1):

A "cheats" method is to write it in LaTeX locally, and include the .pdf in your post as an image.

[image: LaTeX output]

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\resizebox{3in}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1& -1 & 1 & -1 \\ \hline
 & & &\\ \hline
 &  & &\\ \hline
 &  & &\\ \hline.
\end{tabular} 
}

\end{document}
```

The above would require the `standalone` class and `tikz` package.